# TikZ: using ‘node contents’ key for graph nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs

TikZ allows node contents to be set using an option:

```
\tikz{\node[node contents=whatever];}
```

Note the syntax, the following is not allowed:

```
\tikz{\node[node contents=whatever] {};}
```

and gives an error:

```
! Use of \@next doesn't match its definition.
```

Now, when specifying graph nodes, a special syntax is (must be) used:

```
\tikz{\graph {test [color=blue]; test -> test;}}
```

This automatically fills the node contents with ‘test’, so when trying

```
\tikz{\graph {test [node contents=passed]; test -> test;}}
```

we expectedly encounter the error mentioned above.

My question is: (how) can I use ‘node contents’ option for graph nodes? Perhaps graphs allow classical node specification as well (I did not manage this)?

To avoid answers that (only) include workarounds or solutions that are too simple for my purposes: the end goal is to use multipart nodes in a graph in which one part has a default text and the other can be set. Think of dealing with

```
\tikzset{
  Thing/.style={
    circle split,
    node contents={Type\nodepart{lower}#1}
  }
}
\tikz{\node[Thing=something];}
\tikz{\graph {test [Thing=something]; test -> test;}}
```

Comment: Please always provide a complete example rather than a mere code fragment.

Comment: I don't think you can use `node contents` so `Thing` is out. You can use `as`, however, and define `thing` for use within graphs, if you need `Thing` for regular TikZ nodes.

Comment: I wonder why `\tikz{\node[node contents=whatever] {};}` syntax is not allowed. Why is not the default behaviour one over-ruling the other? (i mean node contents=<text> vs. {<text>}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Thing` to create multipart nodes in graphs if you also want it to create multipart nodes outside them. However, you can create a similar style `thing` for use within graphs. This needs to use `as` rather than `node contents` to specify the contents of the node.

For example, if we write

```
  thing/.style={
    circle split,
    graphs/as={Type\nodepart{lower}#1}
  },
```

then we can use this as follows in a graph

```
\tikz{\graph {test [thing=something]; (test.lower) -> (test.text);}}
```

with this result

[image: graph thing]

Obviously `thing` can't be used outside graphs, so you need to retain `Thing` if you want the same style of multipart node to be available there as well.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  Thing/.style={
    circle split,
    node contents={Type\nodepart{lower}#1}
  },
  thing/.style={
    circle split,
    graphs/as={Type\nodepart{lower}#1}
  },
}
\tikz{\node[Thing=something];}
\tikz{\graph {test [thing=something]; (test.lower) -> (test.text);}}
\end{document}
```